# Can you tell me what Star Wars vehicle these are from?

Tags: part-identification

[image]

Not sure what those round grey parts are. They have a blue "light" on them. My son has almost exclusively Star Wars sets but we can’t figure out what these are from.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to Bricks.SE, Laura! These pieces are not very rare, and hence finding the set they come from is going to be pretty hard. With your hint that your son only has Star Wars sets, I think this is from [75166 First Order Transport Speeder Battle Pack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75166-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), where these parts form the engine outlets of the small vehicle.

[image]

Comment: I have this set, and my initial thought was this one too. Does he have a few extra gray lightsaber hilts? The rest of the engines in question are the same part as the lightsaber hilt, except in a color not usually used for actual lightsabers. Also look and see if he has the riot shields from this set, as they are pretty uncommon in this print.